# ¿Cuando usar mapping en java?

Tags: java, stream

Tengo el siguiente código en el que se usa un mapping.

```
// Obtener conjunto de modelos de avión por compañía

    public Map<String, Set<String>> getModelosPorCompañia() {
        return vuelos.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Vuelo::getCompañia,
                        Collectors.mapping(
                                Vuelo::getModeloAvion,
                                Collectors.toSet())
                        )
                );
    }
```

Y estos otros en los que no se usa, aunque no entiendo por qué, cada vez que quiera obtener un diccionario debería usar mapping no?

```
// Obtener número de vuelos por ciudad
    
    public Map<String, Long> getNumeroVuelosPorCiudad() {
        return vuelos.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Vuelo::getCiudad,
                        Collectors.counting())
                );
    }
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. En un código usas el método `Collectors.mapping()` y en otro código el método `Collectors.groupingBy()` ... ¿Investigaste algo sobre para qué sirven esos métodos? ¿Qué entiendes y qué no entiendes de lo que has investigado? ¿Cuál es tu contexto? ¿Cuál es la finalidad de tu código? ¿Qué problemas o errores concretos tienes?

Answer (score 1):

Estás confundiendo/mezclando dos cosas con nombres parecidos:

- la interfaz `Map` (un mapa o diccionario) permite guardar valores asociados a una clave, de tal manera que proveyendo la clave obtenemos el valor.
- la función `Collectors.mapping(<funcion de mapeo>, collector)`, que realiza una trasformación (o mapeo, de *mapping*) de los datos antes de acumular los valores usando el collector pasado como segundo parámetro. Es algo equivalente a hacer a hacer un `.stream().map(...).collect(...)` a la colección con la que estás trabajando.